# How to manipulate xlim and ylim to plot a map in r

Tags: r, gis

For an assignment I'm working on, we are performing a distribution model using occurrence points.  The plot that appears is showing an extent that is too large and I would like to change the xlim and ylim so that the plot is showing the area only with the occurrence points (orange area).  I have tried manipulating it a few ways but it never focuses on the extent that I want. I guess what I really don't understand is what the xlim and ylim are specifying.

```
sparrow= gbif("ammodramus", "maritimus*", geo=FALSE)
sparrow <- subset(sparrow, !is.na(lon) & !is.na(lat))
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl, xlim=c(-80,70), ylim=c(-60,10), axes=TRUE, col="lightyellow")
points(sparrow$lon, sparrow$lat, col="orange", pch=20, cex=0.75) 
points(acgeo$lon, acgeo$lat, col="red", cex=0.75)
```

Comment: I have not used maptools lately, but xlim and ylim should be specifying the latitude and longitude of the plot.  I have not run your code but I would suspect you are mapping everything from South America to Africa.

Comment: your example mentions `acgeo`, which is probably meant to be `sparrow`. Also, start with `library(dismo)` to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
library(sp)
coordinates(sparrow) = ~lon + lat
proj4string(sparrow) = proj4string(wrld_simpl)
plot(sparrow, col = 'red', cex = .75, axes = TRUE)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = TRUE)
```

the plot takes `xlim` and `ylim` from `sparrow`.